# Swift Codable Create Failable Generic Structure

Tags: swift, generics, codable

Let's say I have Login API and response for login success and login failed is different

I want to do this generic way

Currectly I have method which Call API and I am passing **T:Codable** to encode the response

```
typealias completionResponse<T:Codable> = ((_ success:T?,_ error:Error?) -> Void)

static func login<T:Codable>(userName:String,password:String,completion:@escaping completionResponse<T>) {
        self.performRequest(request: APIRouterUserModule.login(email: userName, password: password)) {(model) in

            self.handleResponseCallCompletion(result: model, completion: completion)
        }
    }
```

Now I have created following to solve this issue.

```
struct FailableResponse <T:Codable,E:Codable> : Codable {

    var success:T?
    var failure:E?

    public init(from decoder:Decoder) throws {

        let singleValue = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        success = try singleValue.decode(T.self)

        failure = try singleValue.decode(E.self)
    }
}
```

Issue :

issue is suppose login is successful so in that case I wanted to  `failure` should be nil.

and vise versa for login failed I wanted `success` should ne nil.

**But What happens is none of them is nil** both `success` and `failure` is non nil.However optionals values inside are nil

So Is there any workaround for this ?

Thanks in advance for your efforts :)

Comment: Try Swift 5! Its Result type is just what you’re looking for.

Comment: @matt Thank you sir. But It is difficult now to switch to swift5 . Any other possibly workaround for this code?